# Tips to migrate huge volume of data from one table to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have to split one table into two.

Our currently working script looks like this:

1. disable the constraints of the new tables
2. `INSERT INTO newTable1 SELECT... FROM oldTable`
3. `INSERT INTO newTable2 SELECT... FROM oldTable WHERE fieldX IS NOT NULL`
4. re-enable constraints

In the mean time we also investigate the usage of [parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-2627DC19-7EBE-4C45-A758-711BDB5E37EC.htm) (so far in our tests there were no gains for some reason...).

Apart from that, what else could we use to make a safe and fast migration in PROD?

Comment: Why do you move all the data from one table to another (in `newTable1` you have no filters)? You can [`rename`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RENAME.html#GUID-573347CE-3EB8-42E5-B4D5-EF71CA06FAFC) it or use a synonym if you want it to be in another schema.

Comment: @astentx I do filter in the SELECT. The goal is to have 2 tables. The cardinality of some fields from oldTable has changed from 0..1 to 0..n (that is, they are now represented as an item in a list and have as a parent oldTable)

Comment: `INSERT INTO newTable1 SELECT... FROM oldTable` there's no filtering here. Do you really need a copy of the data?

Comment: @astentx My man, I put 3 dots just to simplify it... INSERT INTO newTable1 SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM oldTable

Comment: "FROM oldTable WHERE ....."

Comment: Let me guess: you're not moving _all_ fields from oldTable to newTable1, just a, b, and c, for example? You're moving _other_ fields d, e, and f, where fieldX is not null, from oldTable to a child table newTable2. Assuming that's the case before we go down a rabbit hole and ignore your original question: parallelism may _not_ improve performance, depending on how much data you're talking about and how your DB is configured to support it. Depends on where your bottleneck is: cpu, disk I/O, log switches, buffer cache capacity, etc. What kind of wait events are you observing?

Comment: @pmdba yes indeed. Well, the tests I did so far are superfluous, I didn't monitor the resources, moreover I did it in our dev environment, which does not replicate 100% PROD. My point is if there is something else I could use that I missed like some specific option from Oracle or something like that, but if the parallelism is the thing then we will work on that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The two main tools for improving large table insert performance are direct-path writes and parallelism, and they work well together.

**Direct-path writes** put the data directly in the data files and bypass creating extra REDO and UNDO data. This features significantly reduces the IO, but it means that your new table is not recoverable until after your next full backup.

**Parallelism** can use extra CPU and IO resources to dramatically improve performance. But as pmdba said, there are lots of weird requirements and reasons why parallelism won't help. The most common issues are using the hints incorrectly and not using direct-path writes. Parallel reads are easy, but to enable parallel writes, direct-path writes are required.

Before you spend a day trying to read and understand the [Using Parallel Execution chapter of the VLDB and Partitioning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/using-parallel.html#GUID-3E2AE088-2505-465E-A8B2-AC38813EA355), there is a simple way to try and test these two features. If you're lucky, all you need is the below code, and you may not even need to bother disabling and re-enabling contraints:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
insert /*+ parallel(8) append */ into newtable select * from oldtable;
commit;
```

If that doesn't work, look at the explain plan, and you should see something like this:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
explain plan for insert /*+ parallel(8) append */ into newtable select * from oldtable;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 1569336347
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT                   |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                    |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)              | :TQ10000 |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    LOAD AS SELECT (HYBRID TSM/HWMB)| NEWTABLE |       |       |            |          |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |          |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | OLDTABLE |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 8 because of hint
```

Look for four key items in the explain plan: "LOAD AS SELECT" instead of "LOAD CONVENTIONAL" means you are using direct path writes, the "PX" operation above the "TABLE ACCESS FULL" implies you are using parallel reads, the "PX" operation above the "LOAD AS SELECT" implies you are using parallel writes, and the "Degree of Parallelism" tells you how many parallel threads are requested.

If any of those items are missing, investigate the "Note" section and it will often explain why you didn't get what you asked for. If you're still having problems, post the full explain plan as text and we can help troubleshoot the issue.